# iterating over a list comparing like items and adding values from csv Python

Tags: python, list, compare

i've imported data from a statement csv and want to cleanse it. id like to simplify purchases into categories and add the values so these can be exported to another csv.

so a brief example would be i have two descriptions one called Esso and one called BP, with debits of £10 and £15 listin in column f. i want this to be condensed to fuel: £25. So i've pulled the two columns and created a dictionary to get the cost and item together. im now stuck.. should i iterate over just the keys to change to categories and again to get the costs or should this be done prior to creating the dictionary? any guidance would be appreciated

```
 Item=pd.read_csv("statement.csv",usecols=['Transaction Description'])
 cost=pd.read_csv("statement.csv",usecols=['Debit Amount'])
 print(Cost)
 
   # Empty dictionary
   purchases = {}
   # Convert to dictionary
   for key in Item:
    for value in cost:
    purchases[key] = value
    cost.remove(value)
    break
   print("Dictionary from lists :\n ",purchases)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question well, you want to create a dictionary like this:

```
{'Esso': '£10', 'BP': '£15', 'Total': '£26'}
```

i.e., combining the data from the columns, without the column names. So, you need to have your columns as series instead of data frames. There are several ways how to read the data. For example, use `squeeze` to read a column from a CSV file as a Series:

```
item = pd.read_csv("statement.csv", usecols=['Transaction Description'], squeeze=True)
cost = pd.read_csv("statement.csv", usecols=['Debit Amount'], squeeze=True)
```

Or read the whole CSV file into a dataframe and then assign the data you need:

```
df = pd.read_csv("statement.csv")
item = df['Transaction Description']
cost = df['Debit Amount']
```

Now you can iterate through the two series at the same time using `zip()` function to get a dictionary as shown at the beginning of my answer:

```
purchases = {}
for key, value in zip(item, cost):
    purchases[key] = value
```

Comment: thanks lenka, i also want to condense the costs so change the names eg esso and bp become fuel (perhaps in a seperate list or tuple) so this can be exported to another csv under fuel cost or simialr, hope this makes sense. i guess iterating over is simple enough but i want essay access to the key and value after. please can you advise? thanks